# ISDATE Validation issue 1753

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `RpParams` with columns called `ParamName` and `ParamValue`. They both are of type `varchar(200)`.

A stored procedure started failing earlier this month.

I have narrowed it down to

```
SELECT 
   ParamName,
   ParamValue =
        CASE 
           WHEN ISDATE(ParamValue) = 1 
             THEN CAST(CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(ParamValue) AS DATETIME) AS VARCHAR(50))
           ELSE ParamValue
        END
...
```

The issue has occurred as soon as the value in `ParamValue` was 1753 or greater. I do know that 1753 - 9999 as considered valid dates, so `ISDATE` is now returning 1 and converting the 1753 value to a date.

How can I validate the field but avoid the >=1753 issue I am having?

This is on SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strings that look like a valid year convert to Jan 1 of that year when converting to date, we want to make sure the varchar doesn't also look like a number.  You want:

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(ParamValue) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(ParamValue) = 0
```